# Looping PowerShell Rename and Move

Tags: powershell

First off, I should mention that I am a bit of a PowerShell newbie.

That said, I have spent some time putting the follwing script together.  Basically, it SHOULD find my anime files, clean them up, and move them to my NAS.  In actuality, it produces no errors while also yielding no results:

```
Get-ChildItem 'B:\- Anime' |
    foreach {
        if ($_ -match "Naruto") {
            $tofolder = "D:\Anime\Naruto Shippuuden\"
            $a = $_.Name
            $a = $a.substring(15)
            $a = $a.substring(0, $a.length - 11)
            $b = $_.extension
            $OldName = $_.FullName
            $NewName = $tofolder + $a + $b
            Move-Item $OldName $NewName -force
            }
        elseif ($_ -match "Hunter") {
            $tofolder = "D:\Anime\Hunter X Hunter (2011)\"
            $a = $_.Name
            $a = $a.substring(15)
            $a = $a.substring(0, $a.length - 11)
            $b = $_.extension
            $OldName = $_.FullName
            $NewName = $tofolder + $a + $b
            Move-Item $OldName $NewName -force
            }
        elseif ($_ -match "Piece") {
            $tofolder = "D:\Anime\One Piece\"
            $a = $_.Name
            $a = $a.substring(8)
            $a = $a.substring(0, $a.length - 21)
            $a = $a.Replace("One_Piece_","One Piece - ")
            $b = $_.extension
            $OldName = $_.FullName
            $NewName = $tofolder + $a + $b
            Move-Item $OldName $NewName -force
            }
        else {
            "I have no idea what to do!"
            }
    }
```

What am I missing here?

B: is a mapped network drive.
D: is a mapped network drive.
I am an admin on all drives this script touches.

If I use a Write-Host command, all paths are correct.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure `'B:\- Anime'` is the right path?

Comment: Positive.  If I run that command alone (Get-ChildItem 'B:\- Anime'), PS returns all three files in the folder.

Comment: You know piracy is illegal, right?

Comment: You know the definition of Piracy, right?  Leveraging a paid subscription and archiving episodes to watch myself is not Piracy.  I am not providing it to anyone else.

Now that we have that out of the way, can we try to find an answer to the question?  Or would you rather go off on tangents?

Comment: Works for me.  Try putting quotes around each Move-Item line so you can see exactly what the command looks like to Powershell.  You might find a problem that you can't see otherwise. If it looks okay, trying running the command against one file from the command prompt.  See if it works that way.